# Proving a sample mean converges in probability to the true mean

Tags: statistics

I have an i.i.d. sequence of observations $\{x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n\}$ and I need to prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$ converges in probability the "true mean", that it is consistent estimate of the mean.

But seems to me that I already have the true mean defined... and have nothing to show.

Comment: Do you have the central limit theorem?  Note that the true mean is the expectation of the distribution on $x_i$.  This is not generall the same as $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i$

Comment: I prefer using the term "population mean".  Maybe I should post a careful explanation of why that is so.

Comment: Note that this is not true if the variance is infinite.

Answer (score 6):

Use Chebyshev's inequality.

First recall Markov's inequality: If $\Pr(V\ge0)=1$ and $\mathbb E V=\alpha$ then $\Pr(V\ge x\alpha)\le\dfrac 1 x$.  E.g. if incomes are non-negative, then no more than $1/15$ of the population can have more than $15$ times the average income, etc.

Apply this to $(X-\mu)^2$ where $\mu = \mathbb EX$ and $\sigma^2=\mathbb E((X-\mu)^2)<\infty$.

Markov's inequality then tells is that $\Pr((X-\mu)^2\ge x^2 \sigma^2)\le \dfrac 1 {x^2}$.

Consequently $\Pr\left(\dfrac{|X-\mu|}{\sigma}\ge x\right)\le \dfrac 1 {x^2}$.  That is Chebyshev's inequality.

Let $\bar X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$, and recall that $\mathbb E \bar X=\mu$ and $\operatorname{var}(\bar X)=\sigma^2/n$.  (This assumes $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ all have the same expected value and the same finite variance, and are uncorrelated.  It is **not** necessary to assume they all have the same distribution, nor that they are independent, although those assumptions are certainly sufficient, since they are stronger than the assumptions we're making here.)

Applying Chebyshev's inequality to $\bar X$, we get
$$
\Pr\left(\frac{|\bar X-\mu|}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\ge x\right) \le \frac {1}{x^2},
$$
so
$$
\Pr\left(|\bar X-\mu|\ge \frac{x\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \le \frac 1 {x^2}.
$$
This holds if $x$ is any positive number at all; hence it holds when $x=\varepsilon\sqrt{n}/\sigma$, where $\varepsilon$ is any positive number.  That gives us
$$
\Pr\left(|\bar X-\mu|\ge \varepsilon\right) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2 n}\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$

All this works in cases where $\sigma^2<\infty$.  In cases where that does not hold, there are counterexamples to the conclusion we're getting here, but I think some weaker assumptions than those we've made might be enough.

Comment: Worth calling out, this is essentially the proof for the Weak Law of Large Numbers (and attributed to Chebyshev in 1867). This can be proved *without* the assumption that the $\sigma^2$ is finite, and only the assumption that $\mu$ is finite, but that proof is more complex (Khinchin 1929, see Wikipedia for details).

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between the two concepts: the "true" mean of the underlying distribution, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X_1)$ and the sample mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$. The goal is to show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X_1)$ in probability as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Yes, that's the goal. Is it achievable?

Comment: Yes, what you should use is some Law of Large Numbers. Then it's straightforward.

Comment: @JacekPodlewski : The statement to be proved here is itself the weak law of large numbers.  If you use the weak law of large numbers to prove it, then that's circular reasoning.